# How to release android app only for specific user.?

Tags: android, release-management

I want to Release app in Google PlayStore only for **specific Users**.

**E.g.** Android Application **only visible** if user login with **example@gmail.com**

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a beta tester and publish your app as beta app. Only the users inside the beta test program can see the app.

More information can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/beta-program

Comment: Sure, if you publish it as a new beta version.

Comment: That link seems to be more about developers beta-testing new versions of Google Play Services than developers publishing a beta-version of their app (although I may have missed something).

Comment: Beta test have only access 200 users